# Rename a volume in single user mode

Tags: macos, home-directory

I have my Users directory on a separate disk on my Mac Pro running SL.  That Volume was named `OS X Users` and the spaces were not playing well with some software.  I (stupidly) renamed the Volume to `OSXUsers` and now I cannot log in.

> "Logging in to the account failed
>   because an error occurred."

I assume I just need to boot into single user mode and undo my Volume rename.  **How would I change the Volume name that OS X uses during normal startup while in single user mode?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to rename the volume.

Use the directory services command line utility to read the current path to your user's home directory:

```
$ /usr/bin/dscl localhost -read /Local/Default/Users/danielbeck | grep NFSHome
NFSHomeDirectory: /Users/danielbeck
```

Set it to a different value (enter first the previous value you just read, then enter the new value):

> `# /usr/bin/dscl localhost -change /Local/Default/Users/danielbeck NFSHomeDirectory /Users/danielbeck /Volumes/OSXUsers/danielbeck`

You might need to enclose a value with space characters in it in double-quotes, e.g. `"/Volumes/OS X Users/username"`.

<sup>I'm not sure directory services are available in single user mode, though.</sup>

Comment: Directory services are _not available by default in single-user mode_, but you can _load them on demand_: OSX 10.9: `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.opendirectoryd.plist`; older versions: `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.DirectoryServices.plist`

Answer (score 1):

To rename the volume, enter the following:

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil rename oldname newname
```

for example:

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil rename OSXUsers "OS X Users"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, `diskutil` by default doesn't work in single-user mode; the error message suggests that this is by design. Apparently it _is_ possible, albeit cumbersome, to get it to work, as some brave souls have determined through trial and error: see http://www.system-fabrik.de/diskutil-single-user-mode/ (article is in German, but the required commands are shown; method still works as of OS X 10.9.2).