# Is it possible to prevent users from renaming volumes in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, rename, user-profiles

I installed a second drive in a MacBook Pro (OS X 10.6.8) and then moved (properly) the user folder to that drive.

Then I decided the space in the volume name was a nuisance so I renamed it. I should have known that was a bad idea when Dropbox immediately complained it lost its folder and Chrome start asking to be the default browser, etc.

In short what happened was that in that relatively simple act of renaming the volume, I essentially deleted the entire user folder as far as the OS was concerned. After rebooting, I could not log in with that user.

This was fixed by [using directory services in single-user mode to point to the new volume name](https://superuser.com/questions/308827/rename-a-volume-in-single-user-mode/308834) (remember to mount / for read/write as indicated by the prompt).

In retrospect, I also renamed MacintoshHD, but I think that's OK because it gets mounted as "/" rather than showing up in "/Volumes/".

But the point is that this is a horribly damaging act which is relatively easy to do. Certainly there are more people that can rename a volume than there are people who can recover from this. So is there a way to prevent this from happening in Finder?

Answer (score 0):

I have always configured our users' home directories to reside on a separate internal HD from the startup volume, and have also run into this issue before.

Unfortunately, there is no *decent* way to prevent users with admin rights from renaming volumes. However, I do have a method that, while still not able to prevent renaming to the volumes, at least decreases the opportunity that it will happen by accident.

Basically, all I do is replace the actual volumes on the desktop with aliases instead. This way, the user can rename the icon that they see all the time without actually renaming the mount-point in the filesystem. To do this, first CMD-OPT-Drag the local volumes to the desktop to create aliases there. Then, in Finder preferences, disable the checkbox that shows "Hard Disks" on the desktop. (You can also do a similar trick for the sidebar if you like.)